# Javascript - read data from multiple files in sequence

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a function `ReadFromFile` that reads from a single file on server.
How do I write a function, that can read from multiple files on server and save data from each file in separate variable in sequence?

```
// Update measure data from files
function ReadFromFile(filename)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {     
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
          dataset_01 = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", filename, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You can just create an array ("theArray"), the length of which equals the number of files you want to read, modify the function you have to let it take two arguments, one being the filename and the other being the index to the array ("theIndex"), then replace "dataset_01" with "theArray[theIndex]"

Comment: If I call in sequence: GetDataFromFiles("data01.txt", 0); GetDataFromFiles("data02.txt", 1); it only reads from "data02.txt".

Comment: Small correction - use `` to mark code (or names of functions, etc) in your text.

Comment: Learn to use local variables and callbacks first :-)